# Add "Place" button to my website

Tags: facebook, web, checkin

I looking for a way to add "Place" button to my website to allow visitors to checkin directly from it. is there any possibility to do that using JavaScript SDK, as popup?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, publishing checkins is documented here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing. In order for this to work you need to:

1. Authenticate your user, using JS SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)
2. Ask for `publish_checkins` extended permission (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)
3. Issue a POST request onClick, something functionally similar to this
   `https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins?coordinates=%7B%22latitude%22%3A+37.383633343607%2C%22longitude%22%3A+-5.9910216821167%7D&place=298525916826786&message=you+funny+lion+at+the+door&method=post&access_token=USER_TOKEN`, of course if using the JS SDK makes sense to use the FB.api() method for this (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/).

Comment: Well, I created already a script that publish checkins on the wall, I described it here: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11827833/checkin-on-facebook-through-popup-window

But what I would like to implement is to allow user to choose the location where he will checkin. 
In method above, places are predefined. 
To understand what I trying to do, is to have a dialog box on website, similar with that from facebook. 

ps"sorry for my English." .

Comment: Can't you simply search for the places

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&access_token=TOKEN

and feed the checkin details from that (doc here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching).

Comment: wish I knew how to do  that :D
Thank you a lot !